# Change dot for comma in chart labels Charting c#

Tags: c#, charts, numbers, format

i have to change the decimal separator of the labels of my chart. I can't put them directly like string because they need a doublé to make the chart.

Here is the code:

```
private static byte[] ObtenerBarraDoble(IList<ValorBarraDTO> valores)
    {
        var newColor1 = Color.FromArgb(187, 189, 191);
        var newColor2 = Color.FromArgb(0, 138, 209);
        using (var graficoPie = new Chart { Height = 200, Width = 700, RenderType = RenderType.BinaryStreaming })
        {
            var chartAreaPie = new ChartArea();
            //chartAreaPie.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd/MMM\nhh:mm";
            chartAreaPie.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
            chartAreaPie.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
            chartAreaPie.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 8f);
            chartAreaPie.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 8f);

            chartAreaPie.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "N0";
            chartAreaPie.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "N0";

            graficoPie.ChartAreas.Add(chartAreaPie);


            var serieNuevo = new Series("Cartera Actual")
            {
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column,
                XValueMember = "label",
                YValueMembers = "valor1",
                Color = newColor1,
                Legend = "Cartera Actual",
                IsValueShownAsLabel = true,
                LabelFormat = "N1",
                CustomProperties = "LabelStyle=Top"

            };

            graficoPie.Series.Add(serieNuevo);


            var serie = new Series("Cartera Recomendada")
            {
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column,
                XValueMember = "label",
                YValueMembers = "valor2",
                Color = newColor2,
                Legend = "Cartera Propuesta",
                IsValueShownAsLabel = true,
                LabelFormat = "N1",
                CustomProperties = "LabelStyle=Top"
            };


            graficoPie.Series.Add(serie);
            graficoPie.DataSource = valores;


            return PdfHelper.ChartABinario(graficoPie);
        }
    }
```

I think maybe in CustomProperties? i need to do this, please help!

Comment: I haven't used Charts in a while, but I think you have to go really deep into the properties and create a style in XAML that can describe the actual text displayed and change it to comma there. I will look in the code i wrote about a year ago, to see if I have a sample. Unless someone beats me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me if you are using XAML? The key is the template style formatting. This is how i did some formatting. If it doesn't help, I apologize for wasting your time.

```
<Style x:Key="SeriesColumn" TargetType="DVC:ColumnDataPoint">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BackColor}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ForeColor}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DVC:ColumnDataPoint">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                Stroke="Black"
                                StrokeThickness="1"
                        />
                    <Grid
                                Background="Transparent"
                                Margin="{Binding SeriesMargin}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Background="Transparent" 
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}"
                                    FontWeight="Bold"
                            FontSize="12"

                                    />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The key is the Template and the TetBlock. if think it's possible to go deep enough to be able to replace , with a .

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not using XAML or i can't find it, i'm working with this using: System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting. That answer yout question?

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realize you were working with web objects, you wouldn't be using XAML. Here is what I think. Series object has a datapoint object under it. Datapoint has a Label property associated with it, which is (if my memory serves me right, i don't work with web at the moement) what being displayed on your chart. Try getting to that property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I got an error when i try to acces to Datapoint. This is killing me!!

Comment: I am sorry, this could spel the end of my help. I am doing this by memory and theory, I don't even have a web server available to me to write a test, currently in WPF development. if you post the error, I can continue to try to help you out. Two heads are better than none.

Comment: I solved my problema, i add this to my web.config: <globalization culture="es-CL" uiCulture="es-CL"/>

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. I was thinking something like that, but couldn't remember how to do it. Glad you solved it.